# facing issue in java with scanner class while taking multiple input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I am trying to take multiple input from user of different classes, if I am working only with String type my code work fine but when I am using any other class like int, flot or any other it ignore the next String input why is this happening can any one help me.

```
Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
String a,b,c;
int x,y,z;
System.out.print("Enter any string: ");
a = obj.nextLine();
System.out.print("enter any int: ");
x = obj.nextInt();                                                                                             
System.out.print("Enter any thing: ");    //after getting input for int it ignore next string 
b = obj.nextLine();                       input
System.out.print("Enter any thing: ");
c = obj.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you call `obj.nextInt()`, you still have the EOL from the Return that the user pressed after entering the number sitting in the input buffer, because `nextInt()` only read the numeric characters.  You have to skip those characters by calling `obj.nextLine()` and just ignoring the result.  Then you can go on and ask for additional input from the user.

This gives you what you expected:

```
Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
String a,b,c;
int x,y,z;
System.out.print("Enter any string: ");
a = obj.nextLine();
System.out.print("enter any int: ");
x = obj.nextInt();
obj.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter any thing: ");    //after getting input for int it ignore next string
b = obj.nextLine();
System.out.print("Enter any thing: ");
c = obj.nextLine();

System.out.println("1: " + b);
System.out.println("2: " + c);
```

Sample run:

```
Enter any string: anystring
enter any int: 12345
Enter any thing: anything
Enter any thing: more anything
1: anything
2: more anything
```